# Difference between static function declaration in C

Tags: c, function, static

What is the difference between the following declarations in C?

`static int foo(){}`
`int static foo(){}`

As I understand the first format is used and subscribed in text books while the second nonetheless seems to work as well. Are the declarations equivalent?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are the same but the first form is preferred:

> (C99, 6.11.5p1) "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature"

Comment: The reference from the specification is really useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the functions you will get an error like " static declaration of foo follows non-static declaration ".

It is not correct in C to use static in this way because static functions are visible in only the file you created

Comment: use any *one* signature.